# Clicking does not invoke click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do this. User clicks .next button -> .btn:first-child after .active -> trigger("click") - > removeClass(".active") -> addClass(".active") to next .btn

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
  $(".active").next().trigger("click");
})
```

```css
.active{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="content">
          <button class="btn active" >1. Page</button>
          <button class="btn" >2. Page</button>
          <button class="btn" >3. Page</button>
          <button class="btn" >4. Page</button>
          <button class="btn" >5. Page</button>
        </div>
      </div>


      <button type="button" name="button" class="next next1">Next <span class="nextBut">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right">></i></span>
      </button>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and rephrase your explanation please? it is hard to understand.

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: Ok, so where is your click logic for the buttons to change the class?

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a click doesn't do anything in this case, because the buttons aren't bound to any click event handlers. I suggest just adding the class directly (and removing it from all the others), like this:

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
  //determine which button will be active next
  const $nextActiveButton = $(".btn.active").next();

  //remove "active" class from all buttons
  $(".btn").removeClass('active');

  //add the class to the active button
  $nextActiveButton.addClass('active');  
});
```

```css
.active{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="content">
          <button class="btn active" >1. Page</button>
          <button class="btn" >2. Page</button>
          <button class="btn" >3. Page</button>
          <button class="btn" >4. Page</button>
          <button class="btn" >5. Page</button>
        </div>
      </div>


      <button type="button" name="button" class="next next1">Next <span class="nextBut">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right">></i></span>
      </button>
```